# Read SOAP message header WCF

Tags: wcf, wshttpbinding

I have a WCF service with ws-security using wsHttpBinding. In one of my method, I want to read the ws-security SOAP header. How do I do it?

I have visited this link but not getting idea. I simply want to read the soap header in one of the operation contract in my WCF service.
[Is it possible to receive a soap message in a WCF method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766738/is-it-possible-to-receive-a-soap-message-in-a-wcf-method)

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jay,

Yes is possible to receive a SOAP message in a WCF method, but what I think you want is to read the header variables in the inbound request.

On the host side, create an object from this:

```
System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders
```

This will return an indexed collection of the inbound message headers sent from the client, and you can read it this way:

```
OpContext.IncomingMessageHeaders(0).ToString
```